# Why does complex Matlab gpuArray take twice as much memory than it should?

Tags: matlab, gpu

I noticed that a large complex array takes twice as much memory on GPU than on CPU.

Here is a minimal example:

```
%-- First Try: Complex Single
gpu = gpuDevice(1);
m1 = gpu.FreeMemory;
test = complex(single(zeros(600000/8,1000)));  % 600 MByte complex single
whos('test')
test = gpuArray(test);
fprintf(' Used memory on GPU: %e\n', m1-gpu.FreeMemory);
```

Now I do the same with a twice as big array which is not complex:

```
%-- Second Try:, Single
gpu = gpuDevice(1);
m1 = gpu.FreeMemory;
test = single(zeros(600000/4,1000));  % 600MB MByte real single
whos('test')
test = gpuArray(test);
fprintf(' Used memory on GPU: %e\n', m1-gpu.FreeMemory);
```

The output is:

```
 Name          Size                  Bytes  Class     Attributes    
 test      75000x1000            600000000  single    complex   
 Used memory on GPU: 1.200095e+09

 Name           Size                  Bytes  Class     Attributes   
 test      150000x1000            600000000  single                  
 Used memory on GPU: 6.000476e+08
```

On the CPU both arrays are 600MB - on the GPU the complex array uses 1.2 GByte.
I tested this on two graphics cards: GeForce GTX 680 and Tesla K20 using Matlab 2013a.

How can I avoid this? Is this a bug in Matlab?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on R2012b + GeForce GT 650. Both gpu arrays are use 6.000476e+08 on the GPU.

Comment: what if you do something like `zeros(100,100,'single','gpuArray')`, what does this do for you? Also note, according to the [gpuArray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/establish-arrays-on-a-gpu.html) docs, complex is not supported so it may be doing something weird like casting it to double when placing it into a gpuArray

Comment: @MZimmerman6: If I do  `test = complex(zeros(600000/8,1000,'single','gpuArray'));` the GPU needs 900MB!? If you look [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/distcomp/run-built-in-functions-on-a-gpu.html#bsp72oi-1) gpuArray does support complex numbers.

Comment: the link basically indicates to me that complex numbers on the GPU need to be handled carefully. The only thing I may suggest is running an earlier version of MATLAB if you have one available to you, and see if you get similar results. see if you can get 2012b as @H.Muster has, and see if it works.

Comment: I think it's to with the complex numbers, surely you'd need to allocate twice as much memory for complex numbers, one single for the real part and another for the imaginary part. Whereas with real numbers you'd only need to allocate memory for the real part.

Comment: Will, this is clear and i you look at the code this is already calculated in.

Comment: Even with Matlab2016b I still see this effect. I'm also curious about the reason.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered on [MATLAB central](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/250326-why-complex-arrays-take-twice-as-much-memory-on-gpu-than-on-cpu). To summarize MathWorks developer Edric Ellis's answer:

- `gpu.FreeMemory` may not be an accurate measure of the available GPU memory because MATLAB does not immediately free up memory when it's done using it. `gpu.AvailableMemory` is a more accurate measure of available memory.
- Transferring complex data to/from the GPU still requires 2x the memory because there is a format conversion that is done on the GPU. Specifically, complex arrays in CPU host memory are stored with the real/imaginary parts split into 2 separate vectors, whereas complex arrays on the GPU device are stored in interleaved format.

Testing on R2017a, I confirmed that:

- Switching from `gpu.FreeMemory` to `gpu.AvailableMemory` indeed addresses this discrepancy in reported memory usage that prompted the original question.
- With 8 GB of GPU memory, copying...

  - 6 GB real array: success
  - 6 GB complex array: "Out of memory on device" error
  - 6 separate 1 GB complex arrays: success